# How do I create absolute paths for INCLUDEs and REDIRECTs that will work regardless directory nesting level?

Tags: php, redirect, include, directory-structure, absolute-path

I have a problem similar to the one mentioned here, except I need a solution for ABSOLUTE PATHs:

[How to use a PHP includes across multiple directories/sub directories with relative paths](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1488267/how-to-use-a-php-includes-across-multiple-directories-sub-directories-with-relati)

The additional bit in my setup is that I have multiple files ("config.php","functions.php",etc) that I'm including in my "header.php" file, then including only "header.php" in my sub-sub-sub-sub-etc folder items.  Basically the header file says "if not logged in then redirect to the top level index.php file".  The header itself is, however, in it's own subfolder called "common_inc".  The problem I'm experiencing comes in when I need to perform a redirect (which is managed in the header) from any non top-level directory.

The only solutions that come to mind are to 1) set 'allow_url_include' to true or 2) place all files in a flat directory structure and work from there or 3) remove the redirect from the header and manually place an absolute path redirect in all files.  Obviously all of these solutions are undesirable.  So can anyone think of a better way to establish ABSOLUTE PATHS ***(for both includes and redirects)*** that won't change based on their request location?

I'm sure there is something amazingly simple I'm overlooking, but my brain is rather fried atm.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

The dirname function may be of use here. It returns the pathname for the current directory.
[dirname - php manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.dirname.php)