# How to use images and php includes across multiple directories?

Tags: php, image, hyperlink

I am brand new to PHP. I want to use it to include a universal header and footer in an html/jquery site. Currently I am using includes to do this:

```
<?php include('../includes/footer.php'); ?>
```

This works fine. Where I encounter a problem is with any images in the header or footer.

An explanation of my file structure:
Root folder: contains `index.php` and the folders "includes", "img", "php" etc.
php folder: contains `gallery.php`
includes folder: contains `header.php`, `footer.php`

When viewing the `index.php` all images in the header and footer show properly, but, because they are linked relatively (ex `"img/facebook.png"`), the do not show in gallery.php. To work they would need a ../ included. But then this would defeat the purpose of a universal header.

Thus I am trying to figure out how to link the images in the includes files in way that is doesn't matter where the php file is located. I have read [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1488267/how-to-use-a-php-includes-across-multiple-directories-sub-directories-with-relat) (which sounds like my problem) but I do not understand any of the answers. I have also read things that suggest `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] .'/folder/';`, in conjunction with an echo to display the image. I tried this in my `footer.php` with this code:

```
<?php
$path = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/img/';
$image = ($path . "facebook.png");
echo "<img src=\"$image\" />"; ?>
```

When I view the page though, I end up with a little torn paper icon instead of my image. I assume this means that the path is incorrect, but I do not know why. facebook.png resides in the img folder. This problem occurs on both `index.php` and `gallery.php`.

After this rather long winded explanation (sorry), my mains questions are:
1) How do I get images to show up properly in my includes across multiple directories?
2) If I am going about this in the right way with the echo, what are the possible reasons why it is not working?

Once again, I know nothing about php, so if you could try to make your answers as basic as possible, it would be much appreciated.

Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Instead of `img/facebook.png`, add a `/` before the `img/` like this:  `/img/facebook.png`

This says "go to the root, and look for the `img` folder there.  All your images should work fine then.  The path of the images are absolute or relative based on the HTML page you're viewing, not which files you use to create it.

Though there's probably not much of reason for a "php" folder - just keep all your pages in the root directory.